# MongoDB + cannot connect to mongodb server using another DB

Tags: mongodb

**UPDATE**

I also tried this to connect:

```
mongo -u root -p 1234 localhost:27017/anotherDB
```

But again, I can't connect.

**END OF UPDATE**

I am having problems on connecting to my mongodb server using another DB.
Here's what I did so far:

With auth=False in /etc/mongod.conf, I connected to my server and created a root user in admin db with this command:

```
db.addUser({ user: "root", pwd: "1234", roles: [{role:"root",db:"admin"}] }
```

Stop mongod service, set auth=true in the mongod.conf and restarted mongod service.
I connected to my mongod server using this command:

```
mongo -u root -p 1234 localhost:27017/admin
```

And I was able to connect. I then, switched to another db and created another user with these commands:

```
use anotherDB
db.createUser(
{
  user: "anotheruser",
  pwd: "1234",
  roles: ["readWrite"]
}
```

Creation was successful. I then ended my current connection and tried to connect using this
command:

```
mongo -u anotheruser -p 1234 localhost:27017/anotherDB
```

But I can't connect and receiving this error:

```
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: not authorized on admin to execute command {getLog: "startupWarnings"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ren is correct, this appears to be SERVER-13588.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running into this issue:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13588

As of the this time, the fix is already in the master branch and is scheduled to be backported to 2.6.2.

Comment: Thanks for this Ren. Silly, simple or stupid question though, where is src/mongo/shell/utils.js located? I already performed find / -name "*utils.js" but any of the results do not pertain to the same utils.js pointed by the link. again, thanks!

Comment: You need to download the source from the repo in order to find it. And here is the link from github: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/utils.js

Comment: alright. then after downloading, where will I placed this file?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Do you want the fix? In that case, the easiest way to do this would be to download the latest v2.7 dev release (unstable) and just grab the mongo binary (http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) or the safer option is to wait for 2.6.2 to come out and upgrade.